Appium windows app driver returns 200 on "click" but doesn't actually perform the click
This is similar to what we are using:
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeOutInSeconds));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(AppiumBy.accessibilityId(idValue)));
element = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.accessibilityId(idValue));
element.click();

This is working fine on Windows 11 but on windows 10 it returns response 200 but doesn't actually click on the element.
Appium version - v2.13.1
